# I'm trying to properly visualise this lambda problem but I'm having a lot of trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

These 2 lines of code are from an exam paper and I'm trying to figure out how to properly visualise how the variables move about. The output is 8.

```
f = lambda x, y: lambda z: (x)(y)(z)
print((f)(lambda x: lambda y: x, lambda z: z * 2)(3)(4))
```

I've tried using online python visualiser websites but I still can't understand how to process works. Is it possible if someone is kind enough to rewrite this as a 'def function()'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` can be written as a function as follows:

```
def f(x, y):
    def inner(z):
        return x(y)(z)
    return inner
```

`f` takes two functions, `x` and `y`. `x` is a function that accepts another function (`y`), and returns a third function that accepts an argument `z`.

The print statement calls `f` with a couple of anonymous functions called in-line:

```
print((f)(lambda x: lambda y: x, lambda z: z * 2)(3)(4))
```

We can rewrite this print statement as follows:

```
print((f)(lambda_x, lambda_z)(3)(4))
```

with lambda_x defined as:

```
def lambda_x(x):
    def lambda_y(y):
        return x
    return lambda_y
```

`lambda_x` is a function that accepts some function `x`. It then creates a function `lambda_y`, that accepts some argument `y`. regardless of what `y` is, `lambda_y` returns the original function passed to `lambda_x` - `x`. In other words, `lambda_x` can be rewritten as:

```
def lambda_x(x):
    return x
```

So you can see that `y` is just a red herring here.

`lambda_z` can be rewritten as:

```
def lambda_z(z):
    return z*2
```

When we run the print statement, we call `f` with the arguments `lambda_x` and `lambda_z`. In running `f`, we create a new function `inner`, that calls `lambda_x` with the argument `lambda_z`. We've seen already that if we call `lambda_x` and pass to it some function, we simply get that function back. So when we call `f` with `lambda_x` and `lambda_z`, what we get out of it is just `lambda_z`.

The definition of `lambda_x`, however, requires a superfluous argument `y` to be passed - to which nothing is done, and from which no value is obtained. In this print statement, `3` plays this role. You can rerun your original two lines of code with anything in place of `3`, and get the same result - try it with `'foo'`, or `3+j` or any other argument of any other type in place of `3` in the print statement - it'll make no difference.

`f` therefore returns the function `lambda_z`, which consumes the final argument `4`, and per the definition of `lambda_z`, returns `8`.

**Blow by blow:**

If you throw in print statements along the way, as follows, you can follow along the various function calls in the resulting output. Here, I've set up the `print` statement with `'foo'` in place of `3` to demonstrate its superfluity:

```
def f(x, y):
    print (f'Calling "f", with arguments {x} and {y}')
    def inner(z):
        print (f'Calling function "inner" with argument {z}')
        return x(y)(z)
    print (f'returning "inner"')
    return inner

def lambda_x(x):
    print (f'calling lambda_x with argument {x}')
    def lambda_y(y):
        print (f'calling lambda_y with argument {y}, returning {x}')
        return x
    return lambda_y

def lambda_z(z):
    print (f'calling lambda_z with argument {z}')
    return z*2

print((f)(lambda_x, lambda_z)('foo')(4))
```

With the result:

```
Calling "f", with arguments <function lambda_x at 0x0000017EC49109D0> and <function lambda_z at 0x0000017EC4910940>
returning "inner"
Calling function "inner" with argument foo
calling lambda_x with argument <function lambda_z at 0x0000017EC4910940>
calling lambda_y with argument foo, returning <function lambda_z at 0x0000017EC4910940>
calling lambda_z with argument 4
8
```

Hopefully that helps clarify?

Comment: Yes thank you so much that's a very detailed and clear explanation.